# Wordpress not showing search field when adding image on some custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, image, search

So I have about 10 custom post types in my Wordpress. And I am using custom fields in everyone of them. I have done all that with Types (https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/)

My problem is that on some of the custom post types when I'm adding an image there is no search field. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORTzB.png

Most of the custom post types it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TMOs.png

What could be causing this and how can I fix it? I have been struggling with this for days now.

Comment: Are there any entries in your error logs that might be related to the types plugin?

Comment: Nothing related to types on log file. But now after I put WP_DEBUG on I can see that the search field is in there but not in the right place. Picture: http://i.imgur.com/9YIz6RK.png Some kind of styles issue maybe?

Comment: Interesting! That does look like a style issue, or perhaps an unclosed HTML element causing some issues later down the page. Unfortunately I can't give you a specific fix without accessing the page and inspecting it myself.